# Pass sass variable inside loop as a selector without value

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I want to use a mixin to give me the option to pass additional selectors as parameters as needed, in addition to the selectors already established. But I’m getting an error here. Not sure what I'm missing, unless you just can't use variables inside of a loop without passing a value to each item and I'm going about this all wrong.

```
@mixin light-section-text( $selectors: null ) {

  @if ( $selectors ) {
    @for $i from 1 through length( $selectors ) {
      #{nth( $selectors, $i )},
    }
  }
  p,
  address,
  li {
    color: $white;
  }
}
```

The desired output of `@include light-section-text( "body", "strong", "strong a" );` in this case would be:

```
body,
strong,
strong a,
p,
address,
li {
  color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't directly pass the selectors list to the mixin function as it would cause $selectors to be the first string. So you have to first declare a list variable and then pass that variable to the function.

Second, you should simply use the `Placeholders` functionality offered by Sass which makes use of `@extend` and the `%` character.

```
%color{
  color: white;
}
@mixin light-section-text( $selectors: null ) {

  @if ( $selectors ) {
      @for $i from 1 through length( $selectors ) {
        #{nth( $selectors, $i )}{
          @extend %color;
        }
      }
  }
  p,
  address,
  li {
     @extend %color;
  }
}
$list-variable: "body", "strong", "strong a";

@include light-section-text($list-variable);
```

**Alternate Method**

You don't even need to use the mixin function as this task can be handled by sass placeholder alone.

```
$white : white;

%color{
  color: $white;
}
$list-variable: "body", "strong", "strong a", "p", "address", "li";

@each $item in $list-variable {
    #{$item} {
      @extend %color;
    }
}
```